# Electron app install error. Error loading V8 startup snapshot file

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge

I have an electron app which I have been distributing by making an installer using Squirrel.Windows. I am using electron forge. I have recently run into an issue where the package built by the electron-forge package step is correct but the installed version installed by the squirrel installer is missing the v8 snapshot file. I can run the executable in the package directory and it works as expected. Why is the squirrel installer not copying the v8_context_snapshot.bin from the packaged app to the installed app after install.

My app packages an executable file with the electron app. This has not been a problem for prior releases. The install error sometimes does not happen for an installer if the executable is not packaged with the app. However, the executable is required to for my app.

Any idea why this is happening or how to get more detailed logging for the make step of an electron-forge build process.

This is my forge.config.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const findExe = (filePath) => {
  let executable = '';

  if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    console.log("Directory does not exist:", filePath);
    return `${packageResult.outputPaths} does not exist :(`;
  }

  const files = fs.readdirSync(filePath);
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    console.log(files[i]);
    if (path.extname(files[i]) === '.exe') {
      executable = path.join(filePath, files[i]);
      break; // Break the loop once an .exe file is found
    }
  }

  return executable;
}


module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    name: "Morpheus 1.1.6",
    icon: path.join(__dirname, "ext/my-logo.ico"),
    ignore: ["env", "genv"],
    extraResource: [
      "dist/model.exe",
      "resources/",
      path.join(__dirname, "../docs/user_manual/book/")
    ]
  },
  makers: [
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
      config: {
        version: "1.1.6",
        setupExe: "Morpheus 1.1.6 Setup.exe",
        iconUrl: "https://working//path//to//public//remote//directory//icon.ico"
      }
    }
  ],
  hooks: {  
    postPackage: (config, packageResult) => {
      const executable = findExe(packageResult.outputPaths[0]);
      const scriptPath = path.join(__dirname, "certify_file.sh");
      const child = spawn('bash', [scriptPath, executable]);
    },
    postMake: (config, makeResults) => {
      const setupDir = path.join(__dirname, "out", "make", "squirrel.windows", "x64");
      const scriptPath = path.join(__dirname, "certify_file.sh");
      const setupExecutable = findExe(setupDir);
      const child = spawn('bash', [scriptPath, setupExecutable]);
    }
  }
};
```

This is my package.json

```
{
    "version": "1.1.6",
    "main": "./build/main/index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "format": "prettier --write .",
      "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix",
      "dev": "set MAIN_VITE_DEV=TRUE&& electron-vite dev",
      "prod": "set MAIN_VITE_DEV=FALSE&& set DEBUG_PROD_SERVER=TRUE&& electron-vite dev",
      "dev-debug-server": "set MAIN_VITE_DEBUG_SERVER=TRUE && electron-vite dev",
      "build": "electron-vite build --outDir build",
      "build-server": "bash build_copy_server.sh",
      "build-cert-server": "bash build_copy_server.sh && bash certify_file.sh dist/model.exe",
      "package": "electron-forge package",
      "debug-package": "set DEBUG=electron-forge:* && electron-vite build --outDir build && electron-forge package",
      "make": "set DEBUG=electron-forge:* && set ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING=true set MAIN_VITE_DEV=FALSE && set FLASK_ENV=prod && yarn build-cert-server && yarn build && yarn package && electron-forge make"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@electron-toolkit/preload": "^2.0.0",
      "@electron-toolkit/utils": "^1.0.2",
      "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
      "electron-updater": "^5.3.0",
      "plotly.js": "^2.25.1",
      "react-plotly.js": "^2.6.0",
      "react-tooltip": "^5.21.4",
      "tree-kill": "^1.2.2",
      "uuid": "^9.0.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.4.1",
      "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.4.1",
      "@electron-forge/plugin-vite": "^6.4.1",
      "@electron/notarize": "^1.2.3",
      "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
      "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
      "electron": "^24.6.2",
      "electron-vite": "^1.0.25",
      "eslint": "^8.44.0",
      "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
      "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
      "postcss": "^8.4.27",
      "prettier": "^2.8.8",
      "react": "^18.2.0",
      "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
      "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
      "vite": "^4.4.2"
    }
  }
```

I have tried excluding the executable from the make process. This sometimes fixes my v8 error but not consistantly. I also need this executable to be packages and it has been successfully packaged many times in the past.

I have reinstalled node modules.

I have deleted all content generated during the build: `rm -rf out dist build node_modules`

I have reverted to previously working versions. These versions now give the same error. This indicates that my nodejs version may have somehow been corrupted, but I see no reason that this version should break my node version while previous iterations did not.